# How do I change phusion-passenger upload directory

Tags: apache, ruby-on-rails-4, passenger

I am uploading very large files to my rails app using apache which is causing my `/tmp` directory to run out of space because it is using tmpfs.  I found the [documentation](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerUploadBufferDir) that tells me I can set the PassengerUploadBufferDir to have uploads go somewhere else.

I have added this to my /etc/httpd/conf.d/passenger.conf:

```
PassengerUploadBufferDir /var/tmp/
```

Even after changing my config file and restarting apache, I am still getting the following error:

> *** Exception Errno::ENOSPC in Rack application object (No space left on device @ io_write - /tmp/PassengerTeeInput-1adfdu9

I also tried to set `PassengerTempDir /var/tmp/` instead, but that gives me this error:

> An error occurred while starting the web application. 
>       It reported a non-absolute socket filename: "/var/tmp//passenger.1.0.778/generation-1/backends/ruby.xQ04mujCtwlJbJBtug08XPh6t9hYXULOc1bCGDMfh7y"

How do I change upload directory?  I am using passenger-4.0.46.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removing the trailing slash from `PassengerTempDir /var/tmp` solved the problem for me!

Regards,

kaese

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same problem, I never actually found a solution to this.  I ended up having to **turn off `tmpfs`**  and not changing my upload directory.

Unfortunately, turning off `tmpfs` varies greatly from distro to distro and in many cases across releases.  You will need to find instructions for your specific setup :(